# Ubuntu as router: Network Layer packets not reaching WAN

Tags: networking, iptables, ufw, routing

I've got most of it working, but can't quite close the loop.
I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 on my Raspberry Pi 3. I'm trying to use it as a wireless access point, but not as a bridge. I followed [this guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software) which has me using `hostapd`, however I switched to using `ufw` with the help of this post: [Ubuntu 18.04 as a router](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050816/ubuntu-18-04-as-a-router). I reinstalled `ifupdown` and am using that for static IP on wlan0. I have a working wireless network that I can join, and it assigns me an appropriate IP. I can ping the gateway, and I can even ping known IPs on the other side of the network (i.e. the gateway of the internet side).
The problem is if I try to ping something beyond that. I get host unreachable from the local gateway. Basically it doesn't seem to have a default route to the rest of the internet if it isn't directly attached. Here's some bits I figure are probably required:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), allow (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
32400/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    192.168.42.0/25           
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
32400/tcp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

additions to `/etc/ufw/before.rules`

```
#NAT Table Rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
#Forward traffic from wlan0 through eth0.
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.42.0/25 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

and lastly a [full dump of my `iptables`on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/jithKh6X)

EDIT:
Here is a diagram of my network. I can ping my gateway, I can ping the house internet's gateway, but if it is something else (i.e. 8.8.8.8) the Raspberry Pi doesn't seem to know that the packet needs to go the eth0 default gateway.

[image: network diagram]