# How to redirection traffic between interfaces on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, server, xubuntu, iptables, port-forwarding

i have server that has two interfaces (enp1s0 : 192.168.1.10 and enp2s0 : 10.20.30.30),
enp1s0 is public interface that we can connect to server with it and enp2s0 is private and isolate interface. on enp1s0 we have web server with port 80.
on the next network (enp2s0 with **10.20.30.x**) we have a ipcamera with **10.20.30.40**

i want to open http://10.20.30.40:80 or in 192.168.1.10:6060 in 192.168.1.x network.

i tried to forwarding port with iptables.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable routing and NAT.

Both are relatively simple to do. See

https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c03023605&docLocale=en_US

Though if you use a different distribution you got to check somewhere else. For Ubuntu check

https://askubuntu.com/a/1051803/216292

Btw: 192.168.1.10 is *not* a public address. Check rfc1918 for details.